# Data disappearing from global array

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, class

I have a global array defined in my parent class and I'm trying to get the array filled with objects populated from a `REST` service `GET` call from a `JSON` file. The idea is that I have the global array defined, filled with objects populated from the JSON files, and then the data will be used within my `tableviewcell` inner class. But I noticed that the data gets filled, its getting the `json` properly, the data is being inputted into the array, but everything becomes erased right outside of the method. Within the inner class the data doesn't exist and even right outside of the network request bracket. I can't imagine what the issue is.

Here is my initialization of the array as a global array:

```
class ContentDeliveryViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate{

public var ListOfFiles: [Asset_Content] = []
public var ListOfTags: [String] = []
```

Here is the method that GETs the json and fills with the array with the inclusion of the print statements outside of the brackets which indicated that the array had been empty.

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    print("short CALLED")
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ContentDeliveryCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! ContentDeliveryCell

    var content: AWSContent
    //fix this
    if(tableView == self.searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView){
        print("search part called!!")
        content = filteredList[indexPath.row]
    }else{
        content = contents![indexPath.row]
    }

    if(content.key.contains(IDENTIFIER)){
        //
        let url = URL(string: URL)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!){
            data, response, error in guard error == nil else{
                print(error!)
                return
            }
            guard let data = data else{
                print("Data is empty")
                return
            }
            let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as? [[String: AnyObject]]
            var asset: Asset_Content
            for jay in json! {
                let category = jay["BIGCATEGORY"] as? String
                let diagnosis = jay["DIAGNOSIS"] as? String
                let perspective = jay["PERSPECTIVE"] as? String
                let name = jay["NAME"] as? String
                let title = jay["Title"] as? String
                let UnparsedTags = jay["TAGS"] as? String
                let filename = jay["FILENAME"] as? String

                let tagArray = UnparsedTags?.characters.split(separator: ",")
                for tag in tagArray!{
                    if(self.ListOfTags.contains(String(tag))){

                    }else{
                        self.ListOfTags.append(String(tag))
                        print("TAGCOUNT == ", self.ListOfTags.count)
                    }
                }

                asset = Asset_Content(category!, diagnosis!, perspective!, name!, title!, filename!)
                self.loadJson(forFile: asset)
                print("RightCount === ", self.ListOfFiles.count)// FILLED ARRAY
            }
            print("FirstCount === ", self.ListOfFiles.count)//FILLED ARRAY
        }

        task.resume()
        cell.isHidden = true
        print("FirstCount === ", self.ListOfFiles.count)// EMPTY ARRAY
        print("TAGCOUNT == ", self.ListOfTags.count) // EMPTY ARRAY
        return cell
    }else{
        cell.prefix = prefix
        cell.content = content
        print("KEY" ,content.key)
        cell.isHidden = false
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: `cellForRowAt` is the wrong place to download and parse JSON. Your arrays are empty because  `dataTask` works asynchronously.

Comment: How do I get it to load the data after its finished?

Answer (score 0):

The right way:

1. load Data
2. parse Json to Objects
3. commit object to cell (by example: cell.object = ...) and let cell configure itself
4. reload Tableview